Cannot find global type 'Promise'
I tried to import functions in index.ts.
My codes
const functions = await import("./avs-directory/index").then(
    (m) => {
        return m;
    }
);

I got errors like
tsc -p tsconfig.json
error TS2318: Cannot find global type 'Promise'.

index.ts:51:25 - error TS2711: A dynamic import call returns a 'Promise'. Make sure you have a declaration for 'Promise' or include 'ES2015' in your '--lib' option.

51 const functions = await import("./avs-directory/index").then(
                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


Found 2 errors in the same file, starting at: index.ts:51

my tsconfig.json is
{
  "extends": "assemblyscript/std/portable.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig to read more about this file */

    /* Projects */

    /* Language and Environment */
    "target": "es2022",                                  /* Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations. */
    "lib": ["ES2015", "ES2015.Promise"],                                        /* Specify a set of bundled library declaration files that describe the target runtime environment. */

    /* Modules */
    "module": "es2022",                                /* Specify what module code is generated. */

    /* JavaScript Support */
    "allowJs": true,                                  /* Allow JavaScript files to be a part of your program. Use the 'checkJS' option to get errors from these files. */
    "outDir": "./dist",                                   /* Specify an output folder for all emitted files. */

    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,             /* Allow 'import x from y' when a module doesn't have a default export. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                             /* Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' for type compatibility. */

    /* Completeness */
    // "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,                      /* Skip type checking .d.ts files that are included with TypeScript. */
    "skipLibCheck": true                                 /* Skip type checking all .d.ts files. */
  },
  "ts-node": {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "ES2015"
    }
  },
  "include": ["./**/*.ts", "index.ts", "runner.ts", "env.d.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
}

what is the problem with my tsconfig.json? thanks
I tried to change the tsconfig.json based the error message but still got errors.
any idea why?

Perhaps you need to update the JavaScript compiler options to reflect es2015 or later.

This question is similar to: TypeScript compiler says “An async function or method in ES5/ES3 requires the 'Promise' constructor”; how do I solve this?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

i shared my tsconfig.json in my question. i tried all answers in the above link.. but it still does not work.
if you need to provide more information, please let me what file should i provide in the question.
